# Vue.js - Adding reactive property to array of objects. Works with local json. Doesn't work when fetched from API

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I was inspired by a Smashing Magazine post about replacing jQuery with Vue. I replaced jQuery powered modals, forms, smooth scroll, etc. within my WordPress theme and am happy with the result!

I'm working on my navigation menu which is easily recreated with Vue, axios, and the WordPress REST API.

Problem is I'm trying to recreate the active state for toggling sub menus on mobile. I'm attempting to add a reactive property of "active": false to each of the objects.

If I copy the json response from the API and paste it locally into my navItems array, bypassing axios.get(), this works :)

But when I fetch that json from the API it does not work :(

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

CodePen Links:

[Non working example - fetching menu items via API](https://codepen.io/JosephAllen/pen/jpRJXy)

[Working example - menu items stored in local array](https://codepen.io/JosephAllen/pen/QBPozG)

```
this.$nextTick(function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.navItems.length; i++) {
    Vue.set(this.navItems[i], 'active', false)
  }
})
```

Comment: `nextTick` executes before the ajax call completes. Move setting `active` into the ajax callback. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ejaJmM

Comment: I swear I tried this. But, you are right. Problem solved!